# How to use an external file to be a part of the main program?

Tags: c

I am writing a very long program and all of them are necessary, which means I cannot just delete some parts or shrink some codes. And guess what, I am programming using an Android via an app called C4Droid.

So, I came up thinking of each 'portion' of the program will be written in seperate text (or any) files.

Im a beginner, so please do give me the easiest solutions for this problem.

Hopefully, all of you getch what I am trying to say.

Comment: You can create a few .h libraries and include them into your main.c file.

Comment: @Stasel Each .h file also (may) need a supporting .c file having implementations.

Comment: for those who will be asking why will I have to do this is because, long block of codes will make the code editor SUPER LAGGY, as well as the compiler.

Comment: @AshRj Of course! He needs to create .h libraries and implement them in .c files, then include everything in the main.c file and compile

Comment: @Stasel Just mentioning it as you missed that in your first comment :)

Comment: How does C4Droid compile and link files - does it support linking multiple C sources into the one app? Your IDE ought to support large files easily: most I've seen cope with lots of lines but not always super-long individual lines. What are you using?

Comment: This might help http://www.cse.shirazu.ac.ir/~azimi/prog88/lectures/15large_programs.pdf Its concise and covers what you need. I also found it pretty helpful when I first wrote a large project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to spend the $2.99 to buy it, but [the market page for C4Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en) says:

> C4droid is a simple C/C++ IDE + C/C++ compiler for Android with GNU Makefile, SDL and Qt support... Install GCC plugin

So since it supports GNU Makefiles and full gcc you should be able to create separate files and just compile them together:

first.c

```
int main(){
   a();
   b();
   return 0;
}
```

second.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void a(void) {
    printf("Hello ");
}
```

third.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void b(void) {
    printf("World!");
}
```

Then compile them:

```
gcc first.c second.c third.c
```

It would of course be better to break that into a header file to have prototypes and common definitions there.. but I don't know how much typing on your phone you really want to be doing; and if C4Droid really has full gcc support, just that should work.